# QUERY for hibernate ogm and hibernate orm together?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-ogm

i test different databases, so far there are mysql, postgresql and mongoDB.
I wrote an insert method that I can use for all three databases.
But until now I didn't find any way to write a function that reads all existing data from a table/collection with all three databases.
so far I used hibernate search and that just worked for mongoDB.

does anybody know an example code or some hints to write that generic query?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read so many things and done so many different ways, I think there is no way to do the write and read querys for all databases together. SAo I stopped using hibernate and implemented everything myself